# Query to find all DML operations performed by all users(developers) on a table

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

i have a table 'x' i want to see all previous DML operations with the name of user(developer) like who  updated the record , who inserted the record and who deleted the the record.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options

1) Create a trigger on the table you want, and write to a audit table you had created

2) Audit on table you want for all DML operations
  Ex: AUDIT (DML) ON TABLE;

[audit parameters doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_4007.htm#SQLRF01107)

Answer (score 1):

It's not just simple query. To achieve this,the database has to be setup.

1) Check audit_trail setting. In sqlplus execute 
`show parameter audit`
If audi_trail = os, xml the audit data is stored in OS level in directory `audit_file_dest`
If audi_trail = db, the audit data is stored in `DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL`.

2) Check if your table is audited.

`select * from USER_OBJ_AUDIT_OPTS where object_name ='TABLE_NAME';`

if table exist here query DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL or os files.

if not execute this 
`AUDIT SELECT,INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE on TABLE_NAME;`

and wait for intruders